# Space Between Unordered Lists

Tags: html

How to reduce the space between unordered list items in html?.
I tried with margin and padding as zero.But it is not working.
Help me to solve this.

Eg:

```html
    <UL>
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>   
    </UL>

    <UL>
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>
    </UL>

    <UL>
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>    
    </UL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `line-height`

**Update:**
you need to make `margin:0` (you can adjust margin value according you.)

```css
ul{margin:0}
li{line-height:13px}
```

```html
<UL>
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>   
    </UL>

    <UL>
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>
    </UL>

    <UL>
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>    
    </UL>
```

Comment: Dear Maddy, I don't want space after 'FIVE'.We may use all the above by one 'UL'. But my question is, is it possible to zero the space between two UL's?.Help me plz.

Comment: Yes, you need to add `margin:0` in `ul`

Answer (score 1):

You can control the space with `line-height`. Between, ULs you can set `margin:0` to reduce the space.

```html
    <UL style="line-height:0.8;margin:0">
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>   
    </UL>

    <UL style="line-height:1;margin:0">
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>
    </UL>

    <UL style="line-height:1.8;margin:0.5em">
    <LI>ONE</LI>
    <LI>TWO</LI>
    <LI>THREE</LI>
    <LI>FOUR</LI>
    <LI>FIVE</LI>    
    </UL>
```

Comment: I don't want space after 'FIVE'.We may use all the above by one 'ul'. But my question is, is it possible to zero the space between two ul's.Plz.

Answer (score 0):

First reset your css.
You can reduce the spacing by using negative value.

```css
ul li {
  margin: -5px;
}
```

But its not recommended as per standard, to be used only on specific conditions.

Comment: Dear WisdmLabs, I tried it. but the listed bullets were gone.What i do next ?.

Comment: Mr. Mohammed can you please create a fiddle an post the link here.
Also specify your actual requirement early at once, changing requirement periodically would lead to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

add following in your style sheet

Style

```
ul{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}
```

Comment: Dear Arpita, I don't want space after 'FIVE'.We may use all the above by one 'UL'. But my question is, is it possible to zero the space between two UL's?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.Add code in the CSS part.
It will help you.

**CSS**

```
 li {  line-height:11px; }
   ul{margin:0px;}
```

Comment: Dear DotNet Weblineindia, I don't want space after 'FIVE'.We may use all the above by one 'UL'. But my question is, is it possible to zero the space between two UL's?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but never use negative values. Because some browsers doesn's accept tp

```
   ul {
      margin: 1px;
    }
```